# PYTHON: Google API directions layers gives OVER_QUERY_LIMIT while displaying route between multiple points after 10 requests

Tags: python, google-maps, map-directions, google-directions-api

I am working on a project to display routes using google map distance API between point A and B coming from a dataframe, I keep getting the error of **" 
[directions layer] You have sent too many directions request. Wait until your quota replenishes"**. This happens only when the number of requests exceed 10. *ALTHOUGH*, I have added a 1 second delay after the 10th request with no luck! I also tried to send the requests in batches with a size of 10 each, that didn't work too! *Moreover, I've read the API documentation*

I have billing setup although I am on the free trial apparently I still have over $300 of credit.

Here is a simulation of my code, a very simple one, for your kind advice

```
import gmaps
import time

dict_k ={}
dict_k['st_coordinates'] =[ '24.760669, 54.704782','25.168596, 56.355549','25.004274, 55.063742','25.000252, 55.060932',
                            '24.872900, 55.137325','24.537609, 54.383664','24.050339, 53.470903','24.211435, 55.424501',
                            '24.196804, 55.855923','24.308309, 54.675861','24.988239, 55.104435','24.985047, 55.071542',
                            '24.306433, 54.490205','25.000252, 55.060932','24.536064, 54.383048'  ] 

dict_k['en_coordinates'] =[ '24.454036, 54.376656','24.130453, 55.801786','23.931339, 53.045892','24.171,54.408',
                            '24.454036, 54.376656','24.130453, 55.801786','23.931339, 53.045892','24.171,54.408',
                            '24.454036, 54.376656','24.130453, 55.801786','23.931339, 53.045892','24.171,54.408',
                            '24.454036, 54.376656','24.130453, 55.801786','23.931339, 53.045892']
key = 'AIzA...............'
dataframe =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_k) 


def draw_map (dataframe,key):
    gmaps.configure(key)
    fig = gmaps.figure()

    for i in range(len(dataframe)):

        start_point = eval(dataframe['st_coordinates'].iloc[i] )
        end_point =   eval(dataframe['en_coordinates'].iloc[i] )

        layer = gmaps.directions_layer(start_point, end_point)
        fig.add_layer(layer)

        if i >10:
            time.sleep(1)

    return fig

df = draw_map(dataframe,key)
df
```

Comment: "I have added a 1 second delay after the 10th request with no luck!"—why do you think your quota will reset in one second?

Comment: it is NOT a quota reset, I am enforcing the application to wait for 1 second before sending the next request. I have read that after the 10th request, you should wait 1 second before sending the rest.

Comment: The question remains: why do you think a one second delay will do _anything_? Quotas don't usually work that way. _Rate limiting_ might, but your error message specifically says "Wait until your quota replenishes". So, um... _wait until your quota replenishes_.

Comment: Hi @Chris, 
because whenever I run the same code again (but with 10 points or less), the message disappears :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a link to the API guide. Spells it out quite clearly.
https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits

You can exceed the Google Maps Platform web services usage limits by:

1. Sending too many requests per day.
2. Sending requests too fast, i.e. too many requests per second.
3. Sending requests too fast for too long or otherwise abusing the web service.
4. Exceeding other usage limits, e.g. points per request in the Elevation API.
   Usage limits exceeded
   If you exceed the usage limits you will get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status code as a response.

This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses and switch to returning only status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT until more usage is allowed again. This can happen:

1. Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per second.
2. Within the next 24 hours, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per day. The daily quotas are reset at midnight, Pacific Time.

Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second.